# How do you get the date/time range for "today" using the Joda date/time library in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Assuming this is how you get the current time in [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
```

How do you calculate values for the variables `dateTimeAtStartOfToday` and `dateTimeAtEndOfToday`?

What I'm trying to do is generate some SQL to do a lookup of all transactions that have occurred between the `startOfToday` and `endOfToday`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would use:

```
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate();
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);

DateTime startOfToday = today.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(now.getZone());
DateTime startOfTomorrow = tomorrow.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(now.getZone());
```

Then check if `startOfToday <= time < startOfTomorrow` for any particular time.

Of course, it partly depends on exactly what's stored in the database - and what time zone you're interested in.

Comment: Note the use of "<=" vs "<" in the code above in this Answer. This is known as the "Half-Open" approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is a wise way to define a span of time. Also, the [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class in Joda-Time can be used to track the pair of DateTime objects defined in this Answer’s code. The Interval class uses the Half-Open approach when making comparisons (`contains`, `overlap`, `gap`, & `abuts`).

Answer (score 5):

This works better, it turns out DateTime has a method called toInterval which does this exact thing (figures out midnight to midnight).  In my tests, it appears to have no problem with DST transitions.

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime startOfToday = now.toDateMidnight().toInterval().getStart();
DateTime endOfToday = now.toDateMidnight().toInterval().getEnd();
System.out.println( "\n" + now + "\n" + startOfToday + "\n" + endOfToday + "\n" );
```

JODA looks to be very well thought out.

Comment: DateMidnight was [deprecated](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) due to the midnight issues. Suggestion is to use [withTimeAtStartOfDay](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method

Comment: It seems that `now.toLocalDate().toInterval(now.zone)` is working as well and it's easier to read (no midnight / start of day hassle).

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeMidnight;

DateTime dateTimeAtStartOfToday = new DateTime(new DateTimeMidnight());  
DateTime dateTimeAtEndOfToday = new DateTime((new DateTimeMidnight()).plusDays(1));
```

Comment: I would suggest *not* using `DateTimeMidnight` as there *isn't* always a midnight, due to DST changes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've never seen there not be a midnight.  There isn't always a 2:00 - 3:00 am, but there is always a midnight.  Or is that just a US thing?

Comment: @Bob: That's just a US thing. The daylight saving change can occur at any time, according to local rules. I found out the hard way.

Comment: @Bob: See http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=233 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateMidnight dtStartDate = dt.toDateMidnight();
DateMidnight dtEndDate = dt.plusDays( 1 ).toDateMidnight();
System.out.println( dt + "\n" + dtStartDate + "\n" + dtEndDate );
```

...but as far as the SQL, I tend to use BETWEEN as the where clause rather than do the > and <= stuff

Comment: This will throw an exception if one of the two dates doesn't contain a midnight due to DST changes. toDateTimeAtStartOfDay is better IMO.

Comment: You know, I cannot reproduce the exception of which you speak.  In the process, working with DateMidnight is better than all of the above as it has a toInterval() method which accounts for the DST transitions with ease.  I'm adding this solution as a separate answer.

Comment: Find a time zone which skips forward at midnight. IIRC, somewhere in South America does that - as I've found out the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

```
if((sinceDate.getDayOfYear() == now.getDayOfYear())  && (sinceDate.year() == now.year()))
   //yep, do something today;
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a Kotlin extension function it looks like this:

```
fun DateTime.isOnSameDay(timeOnDayToCheck: DateTime) =
  timeOnDayToCheck.toLocalDate().toInterval(this.zone).contains(this)
```

This does not contain times equaling the *end* of the day (start is included) so maybe add an "or"-case with `interval.getEnd().isEqual(this))`.