# How do you get the date/time range for “this week” using the Joda date/time library in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Assuming you can calculate the date/time range for "today" [by following Jon Skeet's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525395/how-do-you-get-the-date-time-range-for-today-using-the-joda-date-time-library-i/6525490#6525490):

```
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate();
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);

DateTime startOfToday = today.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(now.getZone());
DateTime startOfTomorrow = tomorrow.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(now.getZone());

Then check if startOfToday <= time < startOfTomorrow for any particular time.
```

How would you do something similar for "this week".

So, if "today" is 20:38 29/06/2011, "this week" would be

```
20:38 22/06/2011 - 20:38 29/06/2011
```

Comment: First you need to define what you mean by "this week". Is the first day of the week Monday or Sunday?

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime startOfWeek = dateTime.minusDays(dateTime.dayOfWeek().get() - 1);
DateTime endOfWeek = dateTime.plusDays(7 - dateTime.dayOfWeek().get());
```

(Note: week days are 1-based)